# Flickr JSON Api display

Tags: javascript, json, flickr

I would like to do the following:

You need to build a page that shows pictures using this flickr service https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/photos_public/.

Users should be able to:

- toggle their favourites photos by clicking on them (please add a selected class to
  the img element when selected),
- deselect a selected photo by clicking on it,
- reload the page, the previously selected pictures should be remembered.
  You have complete freedom to choose whatever library/framework you want to use (both JS
  and CSS).
  The use of JQuery is discouraged.

---

Here is my initial code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
( function () {
function cb ( data ) {
// use returned data
}
var tags = 'london';
var script = document . createElement ( 'script' );
script . src =
'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=cb&
tags=' + tags;
document . head . appendChild ( script );
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I would also like to ensure cross compatibility
for Chrome, Firefox and IE and add tests to my JS code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is pretty broad, it would help if you broke the problem down into specific subproblems. what are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Everything to be honest, I would just like guidance on how to solve the overall problem please

Comment: This question is too broad, looks like a homework assignment. That being said, perhaps this will help: When this page loads it'll call a function (`cb`) with the data from flickr's API, which should be a JSON object you can traverse. You'll need to use this object to create all the images on the page, then create a couple more functions to handle all the interactive features. You'll also need some sort of storage (like localStorage or cookies) to save selected photos.